# spring statemachine set multiple initial state

Tags: spring, state-machine

i have a serial state of order like

```
 public enum orderStateEnum {
        STATE_UNUSED("UNUSED"),
        STATE_ORDERED("ORDERED"),
        STATE_ASSIGNED("ASSIGNED"),
        STATE_ASSIGN_EXCEPTION("ASSIGN_EXCEPTION"),
        STATE_PACKED("PACKED"),
        //and so on
    }
```

and i want to use spring.statemachine(or other state machine implementation) to manage the transition like from  `STATE_UNUSED to STATE_ORDERED STATE_ORDERED to STATE_ASSIGNED STATE_ORDERED to STATE_ASSIGN_EXCEPTION STATE_ASSIGNED to STATE_PACKED`   however all the order data is stored in database,so in my case, if i have an order with **STATE_ASSIGNED** state, i fetch the order state from the database,but  in spring.statemachine, i have to ``` StateMachine stateMachine = new StateMachine(); stateMachine.createEvent(Event_take_order);

when i new a instance of stateMachine, it's inital state is **STATE_UNUSED**,however i want the inital state to be the state i fetch from the database which is **STATE_ASSIGNED**,how can i achieve that? i've read [https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/] but i can't find any solution in it.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new StateMachine you can get StateMachineAccessor using stateMachine.getStateMachineAccessor()

StateMachineAccessor is:-
Functional interface for StateMachine to allow more programmaticaccess to underlying functionality. Functions prefixed "doWith" will expose StateMachineAccess via StateMachineFunction for better functionalaccess with jdk7. Functions prefixed "with" is better suitable for lambdas.(From Java Docs)

StateMachineAccessor has a method called doWithAllRegions where you can provide implementation of StateMachineFunction (interface) and doWithAllRegions will execute given StateMachineFunction with all recursive regions.

So, to achieve what you are trying to do the code will look like this:-

```
StateMachine<orderStateEnum, Events> stateMachine = smFactory.getStateMachine();
stateMachine.getStateMachineAccessor().doWithAllRegions(access -> access
          .resetStateMachine(new DefaultStateMachineContext<>(STATE_ASSIGNED, null, null, null)));
```

I have provided the implementation of the interfaces using lambdas.